# Facebook sdk for ios read fan page wall

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

i want to read my fan page wall from my iPhone application, how i can do ?

Now i have this code for parse the graph api:

```
-(IBAction)parsing:(id)sender{

    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"PAGE_ID/feed" andDelegate:self];

}


- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"received response");
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        result = [result objectAtIndex:0];
    }
   // NSArray *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSArray *from = [result objectForKey:@"from"];

    if ([result objectForKey:@"from"]) {
        for (NSDictionary *name in from) {
            NSString *myName = [name objectForKey:@"name"];
            [self.label2 setText:myName];
            NSLog(@" Log: ", myName);
    }
```

But don't work because he don't parse:

The json file i want to parse is this:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "105744066144184_231235146928408",
         "from": {
            "name": "Alberto ####",
            "id": "1000013568710###"
         },
         "to": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "name": "########",
                  "category": "News/media",
                  "id": "##########"
               }
            ]
         },
         "message": "\u00e8######################################",
         "type": "status",
         "created_time": "2011-09-02T18:30:59+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-09-02T18:30:59+0000",
         "likes": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "name": "Luca #####",
                  "id": "###########"
               }
            ],
            "count": 1
         },
         "comments": {
            "count": 0
         }
ecc..
```

Comment: *sidenote*: the above code is no longer valid for Facebook iOS SDK 3.x

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
 NSArray *list = [result valueForKey:@"data"];
    for (NSDictionary *dic in list) {
        NSLog(@"id : %@",[dic valueForKey:@"id"]);
        NSLog(@"type : %@",[dic valueForKey:@"type"]);
        if ([[dic valueForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
            NSLog(@"- message : %@",[dic valueForKey:@"message"]);
        }else if([[dic valueForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"link"]){
            NSLog(@"- link : %@",[dic valueForKey:@"link"]);
        }else if([[dic valueForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"photo"]){
            NSLog(@"- icon : %@",[dic valueForKey:@"icon"]);
            NSLog(@"- message : %@",[dic valueForKey:@"message"]);
        }
        NSLog(@"------");
    }
```

adaydesign :)